# Constructor not defined: [bnkMIS].<Constructor>(ApexPages.StandardController)

Tags: unit-test

I am getting an error of "Constructor not defined: [bnkMIS].(ApexPages.StandardController)" in my test class.

Test Class :-

```
@istest
public class TestbnkMIS {
    public static Testmethod void TestbnkMIS(){
        WorkLog__c wl= new  WorkLog__c();
        wl.Status__c='open';
        wl.AssignDate__c=System.today();
        insert wl;

      Bank_MIS__c  banmis = [Select id FROM Bank_MIS__c];

      Profile CEO = [Select Id FROM Profile Where Name= 'Standard User' limit 1];
        User uc1 = new User(LastName = 'Mohta',
                            FirstName = 'Neha',
                            alias = 'nm',
                            Username = 'nm@techmatrix.com',
                            Email = 'nm@techmatrix.com',
                            ProfileId = CEO.Id,
                            isActive = true,
                            TimeZoneSidKey = 'GMT',
                            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
                            EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
                            LocaleSidKey = 'en_US'
                           );

        Branch__c B = new Branch__c();
        B.Name = 'xyz';
        insert B;


        Bank_MIS__c bm = new Bank_MIS__c ();
        bm.INST_Number__c=123456;
        bm.Status__c='Open';
        bm.WorkLog__c=wl.id;
        bm.Process_Date__c=system.today();
        bm.Location_Name__c=B.id;
        bm.P_R_D_Code__c='Cash';
        insert bm;

        PageReference pageRef = Page.BankMISErrorPage;
        apexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',bm.id);
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef); 
        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(bm); 
        bnkMIS bankcontroller = new bnkMIS(sc);


    }

}
```

Apex Class :-

```
public class bnkMIS {
    private ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController;
    public  List<Bank_MIS__c> selectedbnk{get;set;}
    public map<string,List<Bank_MIS__c>> branchBankListMap;
    public map<string,WorkLog__c> branchWorkMap;
    public List<WorkLog__c> wrkList;
    public List<WorkLog_Line_Item__c> wli;
    public bnkMIS(ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController){

          wrkList=new List<WorkLog__c>();
        this.standardController = standardController;
        selectedbnk = new List<Bank_MIS__c>();
        branchBankListMap=new map<string,List<Bank_MIS__c>>();
        branchWorkMap=new map<string,WorkLog__c>(); 
        wli=new List<WorkLog_Line_Item__c>();
                for(Bank_MIS__c bs:  [select Name,INST_Number__c,Status__c,WorkLog__c,Process_Date__c,Location_Name__c,Location_Name__r.Branch_BM__c,Location_Name__r.Branch_BM__r.email from Bank_MIS__c where id In:standardController.getSelected()]){
               if(bs.Status__c=='Error' && bs.Process_Date__c==system.today() && bs.Worklog__c==null){
                  if(branchBankListMap.containsKey(bs.Location_Name__c))
                      branchBankListMap.get(bs.Location_Name__c).add(bs);
                  else{
                     List<Bank_MIS__c> bl=new List<Bank_MIS__c>();
                     bl.add(bs);
                     branchBankListMap.put(bs.Location_Name__c,bl); 
                  }
                  selectedbnk.add(bs); 
             }   
                }
    }

           public PageReference send(){
    try{
            List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> theEmails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
            for(string st: branchBankListMap.keyset()){
                       WorkLog__c wc=new WorkLog__c();
                       wc.AssignDate__c=system.today();
                       wc.AssignTo__c=branchBankListMap.get(st)[0].Location_Name__r.Branch_BM__c;
                       wc.Status__c='Open';
                       branchWorkMap.put(st,wc);
                       wrkList.add(wc);
             }
             insert wrkList;
                  for(string st: branchBankListMap.keyset()){
                 for(Bank_MIS__c bs:branchBankListMap.get(st)){
                     bs.WorkLog__c=branchWorkMap.get(st).id;
                     WorkLog_Line_Item__c wl=new WorkLog_Line_Item__c();
                     wl.Bank_MIS__c=bs.id;
                     wl.WorkLog__c=branchWorkMap.get(st).id;
                     wli.add(wl);             
                 }
                  String body = 'Kindly Check the below link and see Work Log Line Items in your Org which does not contain any Pay Slip.\n';
                  body +='https://cs20.salesforce.com/'+branchWorkMap.get(st).id;
                  Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                  mail.setSubject('Bank Statements does not match with any Payslip');
                  mail.setPlainTextBody(body);      
                  List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
                  sendTo.add(branchBankListMap.get(st)[0].Location_Name__r.Branch_BM__r.email);   
                  mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
                  mail.setSenderDisplayName('From Finance Minister');
                  system.debug(mail);           
                  theEmails.add(mail);
             }
               insert wli;
               list<Bank_MIS__c> blst=new List<Bank_MIS__c>();
               for(List<Bank_MIS__c> bl:branchBankListMap.values())
                       blst.addAll(bl); 
               update blst;
                List<Messaging.Email> allMails = new List<Messaging.Email>();
                for( Integer j = 0; j < theEmails.size(); j++ ){
                allMails.add(theEmails.get(j));
                }


                if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
                List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> results = Messaging.sendEmail( allMails );

                 system.debug(results);

                }


         }
         Catch(Exception e){
             system.debug(e);

             }
        return new PageReference('/a1Z');

    }

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Class `BnkMIS` needs to implement a Constructor with a `StandardController` parameter as [documented here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_standardcontroller.htm):

```
public BnkMIS(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    //Bank_MIS__c mis = (Bank_MIS__c) stdController.getRecord();
}
```

If you need a `StandardSetController` instead, you need to change it in your Test as describe in the [StandardSetController  documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm):

```
List<Bank_MIS__c> records = new List<Bank_MIS__c>{ bm };
ApexPages.StandardSetController ssc = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(records);
```

Comment: I have added that in my apex class, can you check

Comment: you are using a Set controller: [StandardSetController](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm) If this is what you need, you also need to use it in your test, where you create the standard controller.

Comment: I changed it to StandardSetController in the test class but it is giving me the same error.

Comment: @manchesterunited I updated my answer, does it look like this?